# Vuetify Autocomplete not returning string instead of object when using "returnObject" prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to get the object back when selecting the value from `VAutoSelect`. Looking at their [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/#item-and-selection) it says you should set the `returnObject` prop to true when you would like to receive an object back instead of the item value string.

```
return function render() {
      return h(
        VAutocomplete,
        {
          props: {
            value: props.value, // the values are being passed as strings
            loading: loading.value,
            multiple: props.multiple,
            solo: true,
            placeholder: t("common.label", undefined, 2),
            label: props.label ?? t("common.label", undefined, 2),
            items: items.value,
            itemText: "title",
            itemValue: "id",
            returnObject: props.returnObject ?? true,
            chips: true,
            cacheItems: true,
            searchInput: search.value,
            closeOnClick: false,
            hideDetails: props.hideDetails ?? false,
            clearable: props.clearable ?? true,
          },
          on: {
            "update:search-input": onSearch,
            input: (values: LabelCodec[] | LabelCodec) => {
              // over here I can see that when selecting the first item it works great
              // but when I select the second item it comes as: 
              // ["uuid1", {id: "uuid2", description: null, title: "Title"}]
              context.emit("input", values);
            },
          },
          scopedSlots: {
            item: ({ item }: { item: LabelCodec }) =>
              h(VListItemContent, [
                h(VListItemTitle, [item.title]),
                h(VListItemSubtitle, [item.description]),
              ]),
          },
        },
        [
          h(VListItem, { slot: "no-data" }, [
            h(VListItemContent, [h(VListItemTitle, [emptyDataMessage.value])]),
          ]),
        ]
      );
    };
```

The items passed to the component are:

```
[
  { description: "foo", id: "uuid1", title: "Title 1" },
  ...
]
```

All of the items are unique as you can see from the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I'm using this component to wrap an api functionality call and that's why the `cacheItems` props.

Is there any prop I should be using here to make sure it returns an object not a mix of object and string?

Finally I was able to reproduce a codepen that you can check it out here: https://codepen.io/whatupnewyork/pen/vYxMRvO?editors=1010

Check out the `console.log`. The first selection comes as an object but from the second one it comes as `string`

Comment: In my console the first one is string and others are objects; if I understand the problem correctly,  you initiate the friends array with string while you should **push** the first item of people array to that (friends), in somewhere like **mounted** hook, if you want to have selected item after load.

Comment: @s.sohi can you give an example please?

Comment: sure, see [this](https://codepen.io/s-sohi/pen/eYvoKLg), just change _friends_ and add **mounted** hook.

Comment: @s.sohi thank you. your example works because you passing an object in the `v-model` and not a string. For it to solve my issue I would require that `value` accepts an array of strings. Check this example using your suggestion: https://codepen.io/whatupnewyork/pen/YzZMvRJ

Comment: You just undo everything in your new example :) , still don't know why you want to use string instead of object but It seems there is no prop or attribute for this particular situation. so you need to change input value from string to object which has that string or change the output from string to object. [first approach](https://codepen.io/whatupnewyork/pen/YzZMvRJ)

Comment: @s.sohi yeah I was afraid that this was not possible. Thank you for the help.